# Remote call does not wait for completion

Tags: angularjs

This is once of the function which I am using to get the total count of objects from Parse database.

```
var getCount = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("MyObj"));

    query.count({
        success: function(count) {

            deferred.resolve(count);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am using the above function in another function as below.

```
var getRandom = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    var Card = Parse.Object.extend("MyObj");
    var cardCount;

    getCount().then(function(count) {
        cardCount = count;
        // This call does not update the cardcount value
    });

    console.log(cardCount); //Always undefined. Not waiting for above call.

    query1 = new Parse.Query(Card);
    query1.skip(Math.floor(Math.random() * cardCount));
    query1.limit(1);

    query1 .find({
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is that the main function does not wait for the getCount() function to complete. Because of this the count variable is always undefined.

How to make the code so that the count function completes and value is obtained before moving to next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getBlouseCount().then(function(count) {
    cardCount = count;
    // put the code that needs the cardCount to be known HERE.
});

// NOT here
```

Comment: Is that the only solution? If so, the code will be like nesting inside each other..

Comment: Nothing forbids you to simply call a function in the then() callback.

Comment: I know. But I thougt there would be some other elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because GetCount is deferred.  It will return immediately and you are then using cardCount without it being set.

Comment: So how this can be modified?

Comment: I think Nizet suggests a reasonable approach.  Nesting is not inelegant, I see it done commonly, even conventionally.

Answer (score 0):

For more elegant solution you can get `count` as argument

```
var getRandom = function(count) {
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    var Card = Parse.Object.extend("MyObj");
    var cardCount = count;

    query1 = new Parse.Query(Card);
    query1.skip(Math.floor(Math.random() * cardCount));
    query1.limit(1);

    query1 .find({
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and then call as `getCount.then(getRandom)`